# using fail2ban with website cloudflare are not working

Tags: apache2, fail2ban

I've installed apache2 + fail2ban and i linked my website with cloudflare.

So i did apply some new regex to the fail2ban to ban ip's requests many times 403 Forbidden Error Message.
I've tested the rule with my ip server work fine,

```
[Definition]
failregex = <HOST> - - .*HTTP/[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?" 404

[block404]
enabled = true
filter   = block404
port = http,https
logpath = %(apache_access_log)s
banTime  = 60
findtime = 60
maxRetry = 3
```

but if i try that with my website linked with cloudflare its not working.

is it the problem with cloudflare ?

I did follow all steps to get the original visitor ips so something is going on there??

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what your configuration example describe exactly. Is the section `Definition` part of filter file `block404` and section `block404` rather a part of `jail.local` file?
Then it looks OK (excepting probably the vulnerable regex, which is not-anchored, containes a catch-all etc).
Otherwise it is wrong (neither for filter nor for jail).

Additionally note that fail2ban configuration is normally case sensitive (due to python's ConfigParser and fail2ban internal handling), so rewrite `banTime` and `maxRetry` in lower-case.

Back to the question - [here is the FAQ in wiki of fail2ban](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/wiki/How-fail2ban-works) which may help to find solution to your issue.

> is it the problem with cloudflare ?

Examine fail2ban.log for the IP (e. g. 192.0.2.1)...
 If you see `[block404] Found 192.0.2.1` together with `[block404] Ban 192.0.2.1` (and probably many `already banned` still several minutes hereafter), then it is indeed something with your banning action (no matter cloudflare or something else).
If you don't see `[block404] Ban ...` at all but see `[block404] Found ...` for this IP, then your `maxretry` is too large or `findtime` is too short.
If you don't see anything for this IP (neither `Ban`  nor `Found`) then something is incorrect with your filter, `failregex` or jail (logpath, backend etc).